# HttpURLConnection response is not working

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

In my project I have url 
like:

```
localhost:8080/myproject/examples/12
```

It contains Json values..To access this field Need to put access key as Header.

Now, What I have done is that :

```
private String doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String desiredUrl)
  throws Exception
  {
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    try
    {
      // create the HttpURLConnection
      url = new URL(desiredUrl);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      // just want to do an HTTP GET here
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     // connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
      connection.setRequestProperty("API-KEY", "value");

      // uncomment this if you want to write output to this url
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      // give it 15 seconds to respond
      connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
      connection.connect();

      // read the output from the server
     // reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
      }
      return sb.toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
      // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so
      // wrap it in another try/catch block.
      if (reader != null)
      {
        try
        {
          reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

this code returns output :

```
Response Code : 200
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>status</th><th>statusCode</th><th>data</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td statusCode="200" status="1">Array</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

But when I am accessing this code in httclient, I am getting value properly..

```
public String ReadHttpResponse(String url){
      StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
      HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();     
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);  
      httpget.addHeader("API-KEY", "value");
      try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
          StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
          int sc = sl.getStatusCode();
          if (sc==200)
          {
              HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
              InputStream inpst = ent.getContent();
              BufferedReader rd= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpst));
              String line;
              while ((line=rd.readLine())!=null)
              {
                  sb.append(line);
              }
             // System.out.println(sb.toString());

          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("I didn't  get the response!");


          }
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return sb.toString();
  }
```

Here,I am getting output properly..

Where is the problem in `HttpUrlConnection`?? What am I doing wrong here?? I have to use `HttpUrlConnection`.Please guys help me out..

Comment: URL is working browser or not?

Comment: you have to add this header in request : urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

Comment: There is no problem in your code because you getting 200 from server side. There is a problem in server end so you get html code from server end. Please check server side to solved this issue.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K, URL is working.I also getting value when using httpclient..

Comment: @Android Developer, thank you.. Now, I am getting the values...

Comment: you did not set header in which you want to accept response . so you get html response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make code logic like this for both request POST and GET. It helps to reduce code complexity. You can make one method for that and pass parameter to it as needed for GET and POST methods.

```
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        // http client

        murl=new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) murl.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);



            if(!jsondata.equals("null")) {
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsondata);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }


        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        }
        resCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("TAG", "response code=>" + resCode);
```